# Lotus Domino search formula

Tags: lotus-domino

I have small method to get connection to Lotus Domino database:

```
Session session = NotesFactory.createSession(host, user, password);
Database db = session.getDatabase(serverName, dbName);
```

So now I need to get some info from db with search() method. And as I know I need to use some "search formula". For example `form="formUnit" & @IsUnavailable($Conflict)`

What type of script is this, where I can find inforamtion about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Notes/Domino Formula language. More info here:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_NOTES_FORMULA_LANGUAGE.html

You cannot use `@Commands` in db.search() and also not all `@Formulas`. Check also `db.FTSearch()` which is much faster in big databases but the db needs to be full text indexed.

Comment: Tnx. And what means form="formUnit" in my example?

Comment: In Notes/Domino the documents/records are usually grouped by the Form they have been created with. It's an item/field on the document. If you think SQL/RDBMS world the closest thing to Form would be the table name.